# three column using div issue

Tags: css, html

I have been trying this for sometime now.
What I am trying is a 3 column layout using div as below:

Header
body - 3 columns (left, center, right)
footer

sample i used:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="left">
    Port side text...
</div>
<div id="right">
    Starboard side text...
</div>
<div id="middle">
    Middle column text...
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer text...
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#header {
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 1px;
}
div#left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
div#right {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
}
div#middle {
    padding: 0px 160px 5px 160px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: silver;
}
div#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The issue that I am facing is that, **whenever I resize the window, the div starts to shrink** - which I dont want to happen.

I want layout something like http://www.w3schools.com/
where when I resize the window, the div doesnot shrink but rather doesnot show the other columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-width.asp) property to stop an element shrinking.

Comment: didnt work :(
still.. even with float property set.. the div comes below one another when page is resized..

Comment: Try enclosing all the divs in another div and setting the min-width for that.

Comment: also, one word on setting the width of a div.. setting width:100%; exceeds the page size (noticed by scrollbar).. any words?

Comment: The margin, padding and border of an element is added to the width. To stop the scrollbar appearing, set the margin/padding of the div and its parents, including the body element, to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to wrap all divs around one which is with some fixed width or min-width set (as someone else suggest).